# WAV file steganography

Tags: encryption, steganography

I'm trying to find a hidden message in a WAV file. It's a song, not some noisy sound. My question is where should I look for the message in data RIFF, FMT or DATA chunk. Should I convert the file to binary or hexadecimal code?

Comment: Critically important, try to find from what original the wav file was prepared; if you get that, the comparison of the two has a fair chance to help (like confirm/infirm that [wild guess](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41052/555)) . Also, try to get as much info as possible about the context, which is most often critical to actual cryptanalysis. Try to find the algorithm used for the stego; whodunit, what kind of stuff is hidden, why, when, how, what are the tools s/he masters / had the opportunity to use. Update: ah, a puzzle; CONTEXT !

Comment: @fgrieu i have cipher but i don't know where to use it and unfortunately haven's found the key

Answer (score 2):

The most naive/common method for steganography is to simply encode the data in the least significant bits of each sample, one or two bits per sample. I'd check there first.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get the sample border from byte array? And how to get sample number? Accordging to this http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/  I have to convert code to hexadecimal right?

Comment: If you are doing it by hand, yes, you would need to work in hex. Otherwise you would write a program to parse the wave file, which luckily has a rather simple and [well-documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) format. The headers in the file tell you where the first sample starts, what format the samples are in, how many channels there are, etc.